# When would a ruby array count not equal to the number of elements in an array?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, machinist

I'm running testunit (with machinist) and getting this very strange result when I run the ruby debugger

```
(rdb:1) @document.document_items
[]
(rdb:1) @document.document_items.count
2
(rdb:1) @document.document_items.length
0
(rdb:1) @document.document_items.size
0
(rdb:1) @document.document_items.class
Array
(rdb:1) @document
#<Document id: 1, title: "Recusandae quibusdam dicta deleniti et voluptate.", state: "published", site_id: nil, template_document_id: 2, most_important_message: "Quam totam corporis similique voluptatibus quaerat ...", delta: nil, approver_id: 1, author_id: 1, account_id: 1, updated_at: "2011-05-06 08:59:12", created_at: "2011-05-06 08:59:12">
(rdb:1) DocumentItem.find(:all)
[#<DocumentItem id: 1, title: "Et voluptatem officia voluptatem omnis voluptas.", body: "Nobis iste nostrum beatae corrupti ea qui debitis. ...", position: nil, document_id: 1, created_at: "2011-05-06 08:59:12", updated_at: "2011-05-06 08:59:12", version: 1, is_heading: false, help_message: nil, optional: nil, template_question_id: nil>, #<DocumentItem id: 2, title: "Ipsum in odio laborum ut officia.", body: "Quas temporibus iusto quidem non repellat. Quia des...", position: nil, document_id: 1, created_at: "2011-05-06 08:59:12", updated_at: "2011-05-06 08:59:12", version: 1, is_heading: false, help_message: nil, optional: nil, template_question_id: nil>]
```

A snippet of my Document/DocumentItem models:

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :document_items
    ...
end

class DocumentItem < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    belongs_to :document
    ...
end
```

Why is the document_items array count different to the number of elements in the document_items? Is it some kind of machinist magic?
(could be related to: [Ruby 1.92 in Rails 3: A Case where Array.length Does Not Equal Array.count?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5434624/ruby-1-92-in-rails-3-a-case-where-array-length-does-not-equal-array-count))

But the question that stems all this is, why is document_items empty? The connections are correctly set up, since this works:

```
(rdb:1) DocumentItem.first.document
#<Document id: 1, title: "Recusandae quibusdam dicta deleniti et voluptate.", state: "published", site_id: nil, template_document_id: 2, most_important_message: "Quam totam corporis similique voluptatibus quaerat ...", delta: nil, approver_id: 1, author_id: 1, account_id: 1, updated_at: "2011-05-06 08:59:12", created_at: "2011-05-06 08:59:12">
```

Comment: What is the output from `@document.document_items`?

Comment: It's in the first line, an empty array: []

Comment: Ah, sorry. Do you have a default scope on your DocumentItem model?

Comment: What happens if you try @document.document_items.all.length ?

Comment: @document.document_items.all.length # gives 2 (just like count)

Comment: Nope, no default scope in DocumentItem.

Comment: show your model code for document and document_item

Comment: What is the result of `@document.document_items.size`? It should be `2` I believe.

Comment: Is `@document.document_items` literally an array? What happens when you call `@document.document_items.class`?

Comment: I agree with Andrew. Sometimes, methods will open up the class of the object it's returning and change/add methods to it.

Comment: @document.document_items.size gives 0 as well (the docs say size is just an alias for length

Comment: @document.document_items.class returns Array

Comment: @fl00r, there's a lot of junk in my models, so didn't want to put it all in. But there is the relevant has_many and belongs_to statements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can happen as follows:

1. `@document` object began with 0 `document_items`.
2. Two `DocumentItem` objects were created directly, i.e., not through the `@document.document_items` association.

If you do not reload `@document` at this point, then `length` only returns the size of the document_items array cached in memory for the `@document` object, which is 0. However, `count` goes to the database, and returns 2 as expected.

In order to get around it, you need to explicitly call `reload` on `@document` after creating the new `DocumentItem` objects.

Comment: Thanks! The problem was machinist didn't load the document object when document items were added.